# Can some help me figure out is my code printing my variable out like this

Tags: python, variables, printing

I just started learning python and I need to print out my variable, but it's printing it in a weird way.

```py
namesANDgrade = ""

while studentname == 'y':
  NumberOfStudents += 1
  print("Enter student#",NumberOfStudents,"name")
  name = input()
  namesANDgrade = str(namesANDgrade) + '\n'+str(NumberOfStudents)+":"+str(name)
  print("What is",name+'s grade in the class: ')
  grade = input()

  namesANDgrade = str(namesANDgrade),str(grade)+"%"

print(namesANDgrade)
```

James Karen and the numbers are inputted

when namesANDgrade is printed it displays as:

```
("('\\n1:James ', '90%')\n2:Karen", '50%')

I expect it to be:

1:James 90%

2:Karen 50%
```

Comment: what does `while studentname == 'y':` mean? `studentname` is undefined and is never modified inside the loop.

Comment: replace the commas `,` with plus signs `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using commas in the variable converts the variable into a tuple of strings.

Instead,

Its easier and personally a convenient way to just use the 'f' strings, if you're using Python3.

```
 namedANDgrade = f'{str(namesANDgrade)} {str(grade)}% \n'
```

For Python2:

```
 namedANDgrade = '{} {}% \n'.format(str(namesANDgrade),str(grade))
```

This way its clean and easier to read and organize your code

Answer (score 2):

Using a comma (`,`) in `namesANDgrade = str(namesANDgrade),str(grade)+"%"` sets `namesAndgrade` to be a tuple of two items: a string version of itself and then a string made of the grade and `%`.

Instead, just use plus to do a string concatenation. Also, a lot of these `str` calls are redundant, because the return value of `input` is a string and string concatenations produce a string:

```
namesANDgrade = ""

while studentname == 'y': # this looks like an infinite loop but it's in the question 
  NumberOfStudents += 1
  print("Enter student#",NumberOfStudents,"name")
  name = input()
  namesANDgrade = namesANDgrade + '\n' + str(NumberOfStudents) + ":" + name
  print("What is " + name + "'s grade in the class: ")
  grade = input()

  namesANDgrade = namesANDgrade + grade + "%"

print(namesANDgrade)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Helped a lot.